# centering the svg component after the zoom function in d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, center

I'm using d3js to build a tree, because the tree size is very big, and my container is small, so the div cannot show the svg component on page load, like this
[image on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prFbe.png)

In order to show the tree, i have to zoom in and drag the svg component,
like this 
[zoomed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyAL3.png)

Is there any way to center the svg component inside the svg when the page load?

here is my code

```
<style>

        .node circle {
          fill: #fff;
          stroke: steelblue;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node {
          font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #ccc;
          stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        </style>
          <!--<img src="../image/dummy5.svg" style='width:100%;margin:3px 0;'/>-->
          <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
          <!--******* vertical *******-->
          <script>
          var treeData = [
            <?php echo "{'name' : 'CDS','icon': '../image/logo.png','padding':'0','user_id': 'CDS','level':'CDS','children' : ["; echo get_node_ul_frm_adm ($DBconn, 1); echo "]}"; ?>];

            var width = $("#agent-tree").width(),
              height = 2200;

          var cluster = d3.layout.tree()
              .nodeSize([100, 200])
              .separation(function(){
                return .5;
              })
              .size([height, width - 160]);

          var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
              svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
              })

          var svg = d3.select("#agent-tree").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height)
              .attr("object-fit", "cover")
              .call(zoom)
              .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");
              root = treeData[0];
            var nodes = cluster.nodes(root).reverse();
            nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });
            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(cluster.links(nodes))
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", elbow);

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

            node.append("circle")
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0,"+d.padding+")"; })
                .attr("r", 12.5);

          function elbow(d) {
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
              + "H" + ((d.target.x-d.source.x)/2,d.source.x )
              + "V" + d.target.y
              + "H" + d.target.x
              + "v" + ((d.source.y-d.target.y)/2,42 );
          }
          </script>
```

Comment: I take it my answer is not what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Go through each node on the tree and get the smallest and biggest x and y values of each of their corresponding bounding boxes.

```
var smallestBiggestDim = {
  smallX : "",
  smallY : "",
  bigX : "",
  bigY : ""
}
nodes.each(function(d, i){ //loop through tree nodes
  var thisBBox = d3.select(this).node().getBBox(); //get bbox of current node
  if(i == 0){
    //if i = 0, none are set, so set them
    smallestBiggestDim.smallX = thisBBox.left;
    smallestBiggestDim.smallY = thisBBox.top;
    smallestBiggestDim.bigX = thisBBox.left + thisBBox.width;
    smallestBiggestDim.bigY = thisBBox.top + thisBBox.height;
  } else {
    //check values and set if bigger or smaller
    if(smallestBiggestDim.smallX > thisBBox.left){ smallestBiggestDim.smallX = thisBBox.left }
    if(smallestBiggestDim.smallY > thisBBox.top){ smallestBiggestDim.smallY = thisBBox.top }
    if(smallestBiggestDim.bigX < thisBBox.left + thisBBox.width;){ smallestBiggestDim.bigX = thisBBox.left + thisBBox.width; }
    if(smallestBiggestDim.bigY < thisBBox.top + thisBBox.height;){ smallestBiggestDim.bigY = thisBBox.top + thisBBox.height; }
}
})
```

The above gets the bounding box of each node and checks for the smallest and biggest x and y values.

Then use these dimensions along with the width and height of your svg to work out the zoom.

To work out the new width and height just do :

```
var newWidth = smallestBiggestDim.bigX - smallestBiggestDim.smallX;
var newHeight = smallestBiggestDim.bigY - smallestBiggestDim.smallY;
```

Say your calculated rect was 300 x 300 and your width and height of your svg was 200 x 200. To calculate the scale you would do :

```
var scale = Math.max(rectWidth/svgWidth, rectHeight/svgHeight);
//which is
var scale = Math.max(300/200, 300/200);
```

I use Math.max as you only have one scale value so you need to get the maximum value to fit both the width and height in.

So your scale would now be :

```
var newScale = 1.5
```

So on load you would zoom out like so :

```
svg.attr('transform', 'scale(' + newScale + ')';
```

That should work :)